# нырк, прыг - предикатив?

Tags: предикатив

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в предложениях: "Нырк в нору" или "Прыг в котёл и там сварился", - какой частью речи являются "нырк" и "прыг"?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Предикативом.

Разве есть такая часть речи - предикатив?

И еще вопрос.
Шапиро пишет:[Типы сказуемых](http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200304304)

...Именная часть сказуемого может быть выражена <...> инфинитивом – Его утеха – по лесам скитаться за зверями. (В.А. Жуковский);

Но здесь, по-моему, утеха - сказуемое.

[Руссовед](http://rusoved.ru/pravila/podlegashee.html:)

Местоположение подлежащего, выраженного инфинитивом, в предложении не закреплено (например, за абсолютным началом предложения); ср.: Дело нужное — учиться. Если в предложении один из главных членов выражен существительным в И. п. , а другой — инфинитивом, то инфинитив будет выступать как подлежащее.

Comment: Дум,  вопрос вы взяли с Грамоты? Они почему-то ответили, что это предикатив.

Answer (score 5):

Как часть речи это глагольное междометие. Как член предложения это обычно глагольное сказуемое со значением мгновенного действия в прошлом.

Answer (score 3):

Нырк и прыг - это "усеченные  формы глагола интенсивного  действия, иногда их называют глагольными междометиями. Они выполняют роль простого глагольного сказуемого и обычно всегда имеют с добавочное экспрессивное значение.

Но ПГС, как правило,  выражается спрягаемыми формами глагола, имеющими показатели времени. Очевидно, в этом случае время действия усеченного глагола определяется по контексту.

Он держит скользкую удочку. И вдруг она резко прыг! прыг! (прыгает, начинает прыгать)

С пассажирского места ― прыг! ― выпархивает девушка (выпрыгивает).

А налим ― прыг из оставленного ведра, и запрыгал по лестнице (выпрыгнул).

Answer (score 1):

doom, согласно современным представлениям (не общепризнанным, согласен) предикатив, или "категория состояния", - часть речи.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2

Можно вести академические споры в отношении того, является ли тут слово местоимением или предикативом. Я не берусь выступать судьей в этом споре, но если выбрать второй подход, то нет причин отказывать этому предикативу в праве быть частью речи. Так что ответ "Справки" вполне можно считать одним из возможных правильных.